# Running paparzzi UAV in git bash

Tags: windows-10, python, python3, git-bash

I got this error when trying to running paparazzi UAV in git bash. can anyone help me solve this problem ?

`/usr/bin/env: ‘/usr/bin/python3’: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Running on Windows with git-bash is not supported, you need WSL. Follow [the documentation](https://wiki.paparazziuav.org/wiki/Installation/Windows10). You need to first install Ubuntu WSL, then [install the prerequisites for Paparazzi](https://paparazzi-uav.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/install.html), including Python.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).